# I trying to update some records with Inner join in JPA Query but we getting some exception

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

This is MySQL query:

```
UPDATE grademyadvisor.gma_error AS ge
        INNER JOIN
    grademyadvisor.yodlee_error_code AS yec ON yec.id = ge.yodlee_error_id 
SET 
    ge.is_resolved = 0
WHERE
    ge.client_id = 639
        AND yec.error_code = 402;
```

> Spring Data JPA Query And getting Exception.  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'INNER' near line 1, column 39 [ UPDATE com.gma.domain.GMAError AS ge INNER JOIN ge.yodleeErrorCode AS yec SET ge.isResolved=:isResolved WHERE ge.client.id=:clientId AND yec.errorCode=:errorCode ]

```
@Query(" UPDATE GMAError AS ge "
        + "INNER JOIN ge.yodleeErrorCode AS yec "
        + "SET ge.isResolved=:isResolved "
        + "WHERE ge.client.id=:clientId "
        + "AND yec.errorCode=:errorCode ")
```

Comment: Message is self explanatory. Your JPQL UPDATE query has invalid syntax. UPDATE needs "SET xxx = yyy" etc, and cannot have INNER JOIN. As any JPA documentation would tell you

Comment: The exception message, while quite informative, does not answer the question. The asker wants some way to do it. If not this way, what are the best alternatives? It is a useful, valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery in the WHERE clause to get rid of the INNER JOIN statement:

```
UPDATE grademyadvisor.gma_error
SET 
    is_resolved = 0
WHERE
    client_id = 639
AND yodlee_error_id = (SELECT id FROM grademyadvisor.yodlee_error_code WHERE error_code = 402);
```

Comment: Thanks SaschaM78 for reply, this approach i already used that is fine. But we need with inner join i think you know we are usually prefer because joins will work faster than sub queries.